# using the activityController to share label

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have the following code

```
 let textToShare = "Check out the test original for \(String(describing: bookTitle.text))"

        if let myWebsite = URL(string: "X") {//Enter link to your app here
            let objectsToShare = [textToShare, myWebsite] as [Any]
            let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

            //Excluded Activities
            activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivity.ActivityType.airDrop, UIActivity.ActivityType.addToReadingList]

            activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender
            self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

When i try to share the label text bookTitle.text, I get the output Optional("Test"). Is there a way to share UILabel text using the UIActivityViewController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get the output Optional("Test")

Actually, you're in the right way. Except you need to "unwrap" that optional property `.text`. You can do it in so many ways. One way is to force unwrap it (not recommended most of the time!) Like so:

```
let textToShare = "Check out the test original for \(bookTitle.text!)"
```

Or one more way is to use `nil coalescing`. Like so:

```
let textToShare = "Check out the test original for \(bookTitle.text ?? "")"
```

More about **Optional Chaining** https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OptionalChaining.html

P.S no need to use `String(describing:)`. You use it usually in `print()`.